# ANSI Color Escape Sequences Different Foreground and Background color with 256 colors

Tags: python, colors, ansi-escape

I'm using the ANSI Escape Sequence codes to add color to terminal output in my program.

I am mainly using this code, where COLOR can be any value between 0 and 255 to achieve great color variation.

```
\033[38;5;COLOR;1m TEXT \u001b[0m
```

The problem is that using the 256 color spectrum I am unable to have the "background" (7m) be colored with the string in the foreground being colored as well.

Using this format I am able to have the background and foreground have their own colors, but I am no longer able to use 256 colors, being reverted to 8 or so...

```
\x1b[1;32;41m Green On Red \x1b[0m"
```

After extensive testing with values and formats, I have not found a way to have separately colored background and foreground with the 256 color spectrum. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which terminal? (Please never use directly the escape-sequences, assuming a 256colour terminal is a huge assumption, and assuming that all terminals interpret the escape sequences in the same manner is too much)

Comment: It depends on your OS and terminal, but in theory `38` sets the fg color, and `48` sets the bg

Comment: 256 colors normally works for my MacOS terminal.
Sadly, replacing the 38 and 48 values (as mentioned I have tested) limits me to a range of 31-39 and 41-49, since the first number defines if its a bg or fg color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure it out!

I simply run the escape sequence twice before the text. Once for background color, once for foreground color.

```
\033[48;5;(ONE OF 256 COLORS)m\033[38;5;(ONE OF 256 COLORS)m TEXTHERE \033[0;0m
```

This allows me to use the whole 256-color spectrum in both BG and FG, no imports or addons needed.